# Free online application for doing scrum on rails

Tags: agile, iteration, scrum, backlog

What is the best free online software to help do agile development and management on my ruby on rails application?

What I am looking for is an online form that multiple people can interact with with the ability to do:

- Planning poker
- Iterations/sprints
- Velocity calculations/predictions
- Backlog prioritization
- Stories with point values

**Bonus:**
And maybe a way to integrate with github

I have tried scrumdo but just wondered if there is a better free application.

Comment: Do you need this application to run on RoR? If not, you might want to remove RoR from the question as the language and development tools have little impact on Agile methodology.

Comment: I was hoping that i would find a tool that was maybe made for ROR but i guess you are right ill remove RoR

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of suggestions for online scrum management -

- [See now do](https://www.seenowdo.com/index.xhtml)
- [Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

All this time (14 years) of professional activity, I've been searching for the best tools. Since Agile Hyping the research continue and I want to give you my piece of contribution.:

I've never seen a tool like [Target Process](https://www.targetprocess.com/) for managment of SCRUM and Kanban.

The tool is AWESOME!

Cons.: Doesn't have Planning Poker. Doesn't have timer to tasks. You have to input.

Pro.: Bugtracking integrated. Constantly updates. Free to 5 people team.

If you want I can share my review of some tested tools.

Comment: Your answer reads like the flyer of a marketing group. Please focus on the facts, not your personal opinions!